# Flexbox align-content not aligning

Tags: css, flexbox

So this is the scenario, I have some containers within containers. I cannot get the flexbox to use `space-between`.

Let's say we have a container that looks something like:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 2px solid black;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sub-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid black;
  flex-basis: 50px;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: 25px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  Hello this is some content
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When this is run it should have an item on the left and the right of `sub-container` and as you can see it doesn't.

Comment: A trick is to open the inspector (right-click on the element, and select Inspect [Element]), and then type `align-content:` in element[.style] and use your arrow keys to try different values. I always mix up `align-content` with `justify-content` and see what happens when the value changes makes me realize my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **`justify-content`** not `align-content`

> The CSS justify-content property defines how the browser distributes space between and around content items along the **main-axi**s of a flex container, and the inline axis of a grid container.
>
> [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 2px solid black;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sub-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid black;
  flex-basis: 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: 25px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  Hello this is some content
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSS declaration you're looking for is:

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.sub-container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid black;
  flex-basis: 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  flex-basis: 25px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
<div class="sub-container">
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
Hello this is some content
<div class="sub-container">
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>    
</div>
</div>
```